# How store website content?

Tags: php, mysql, web-crawler, bigdata

I write script PHP which should crawl all sub-pages of one domain, upload text(all keywords) from sub-page to database(MySQL). Next, I want to fast find url's with specific keyword. How to keep and work with big text data in my case? It should work like google's site crawler

I found 2 solutions:

1. Upload text to one column with FULLTEXT
2. Create 2 tables: keywords, keyword-subpage with keys: keyword id, sub-page id

Could you recommend another solutions, methods?

Comment: You might want to have a look at No-SQL databases. for example MonoDB.  Its a complete different approach and *might* work for you, but there more factors you need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You could process the full html in-memory using regular expressions and then saving only the relevant data to your database, or save the full-text to your database for batch processing. Here's an article about [regular expression crawling](http://nathanael.hevenet.com/simple-php-web-crawler/).

For example, this regex pattern would match hyperlinks in the html:

```
preg_match_all( '/http:\/\/[^ "\']+/', $content, $matches );
```

Comment: If that answers your question, kindly mark it as the answer. Else, let me know if you have other doubts.